# how do i install pyaudio on windows ten for python 3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, python-3.8, pyaudio

I downloaded py audio on windows ten but when i run the code it says please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first. When i did pip install portAudio or pip install port audio it said:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\stewa\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\stewa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0ync7n97\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\stewa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0ync7n97\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-cg067rmb'
         cwd: C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0ync7n97\audio.coders\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0ync7n97\audio.coders\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full 
command 
output.
```

Does anyone know what i should do?
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the python wheels only provide support up to version 3.6 of python.
Apparently you're using the latest version, I've tested it on my system (Win10) using python 3.6 using this command:

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

And it works

> Learn more about it [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#binaries)

Answer (score 0):

That probably happened because you got the wrong PyAudio version. You have to get the compatible version with your windows(32 or 64) and with python.
check [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

First you have to uninstall PyAudio first using the command `pip uninstall pyAudio`

Then after you getting the right version you got to the repository and install it.

Example: `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`

These steps solved the issue for me

Comment: I tried this but when i uninstalled pyAudio this happend:

Comment: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: also when i tried it on python 3.6 it said import error no module named gtts (gtts works on python 8) before i could see if pyaudio works

Comment: so im guessing that python 3.6 doesn't support gtts so is there a version that supports pyaudio and gtts on windows 10? thanks

Comment: it also says no module named speechrecognition

Comment: Hello, what are you using for python? I recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads) as a package manager so you can easily swap different python versions on the fly and you can install packages that aren't usually available on windows.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows OS run:**

```sh
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

**For Linux OS run:**

```sh
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0
pip install pyaudio --user
```